# Why do I keep getting a read access violation? C++

Tags: c++

I keep running through the program and changing around pointers and I don't see what I am missing. I keep getting a read access violation on line 42 of the .cpp file and I am genuinely confused on how.

Here is the .cpp file

```
#include "Graph.h";

void Graph::insertEdge(int from, int to, int weight)
{
    if (from <= size && to <= size)
    {
        bool leave = true;
        EdgeNode* current = vertices[from].edgeHead;
        while (leave)
        {
            if (from == current->adjVertex || current == nullptr) //Read access violation here
            {
                current->weight = weight;
                if (current == nullptr)
                {
                    current->adjVertex = to;
                    current->nextEdge = nullptr;
                }
                leave = false;
            }
            else
                current = current->nextEdge;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the .h file

```
#include "Vertex.h";
#include <fstream>;
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    static const int MAX_VERTICES = 101;
    struct EdgeNode 
    {
        int adjVertex = 0;          
        int weight = 0;             
        EdgeNode* nextEdge = nullptr;
    };

    struct VertexNode 
    {
        EdgeNode* edgeHead = nullptr;
        Vertex* data = nullptr;         
    };

    struct Table 
    {
        bool visited;           
        int dist;               
        int path;               
    };

public:
    void buildGraph(ifstream& in);
    void insertEdge(int from, int to, int weight);
    void removeEdge(int beginning, int end);
    void findShortestPath();
    void displayAll();
    void display(int begin, int end);

private:
    int size;                   
    VertexNode vertices[MAX_VERTICES]; 
    Table T[MAX_VERTICES][MAX_VERTICES];
};
```

I've been on this problem for multiple hours now and I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: This is where a debugger can quickly pinpoint the problem. Which line 42? You need to give us a hint as to where that is.

Comment: Maybe `if (current == nullptr)` means `current->adjVertex = to` is a *really bad idea*. Do you mean `!= nullptr`?

Comment: If you try to derefence a NULL pointer (like `current`) you will usually get a read access violation.

Comment: My bad, I have a comment next to the line of code that is causing me issues. The current variable in particular

Comment: What I was attempting to do is that if the EdgeNode is null, i would fill it up with variables like the to parameter

Comment: It's rather pointless to check for `current == nullptr` **after** you've already attempted to dereference `current`. If it's in fact `nullptr`, the program will crash before getting to that check.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it's even worse than that - using a pointer before you check it can let the optimizer take out the check entirely!  See [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: @YoelGebrehiwet -- *I've been on this problem for multiple hours now and I can't seem to find the issue* -- If  after this line: `EdgeNode* current = vertices[from].edgeHead;`, the `current == nullptr`, you have no choice but to have it point somewhere valid *before* you dereference it.  Basically your code has `nullptr->adjVertex = to;` -- does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes! I figured out what I needed to fix, I realized that I needed to create a new EdgeNode before actually filling it with any variables, thank you all for helping me out! I don't know why that slipped from my thought process.

Comment: Test versus `nullptr` **before** exercising your pointers, not after. `from == current->adjVertex || current == nullptr` has it backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably instead of

```
 if (from == current->adjVertex || current == nullptr)
```

you should first ensure the pointer is not null before dereferencing it.

```
 if (current == nullptr || from == current->adjVertex)
```

then if current is null, the right-hand side of || operator won't be run.

HOWEVER, you will still have a problem because you also dereference current->weight inside the if-statement, even if current is null.